# Acessing property in a method

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm making simple JS game just for practice. I came across an issue that I don't really know how to name it. The title is maybe completely incorrect. But anyway, here is my code.

```
    function Battle () {
    this.name;
    this.pointsAmount = 100;
    this.attack = function attack (opponent) {
        opponent.pointsAmount -= 30;
        alert(this.name + " hit " + opponent.name);
    };
};

var player1 = new Battle ();
var player2 = new Battle ();

// players
player1.name = "Lorem";
player2.name = "Ipsum";

player1.attack(player2);
    alert(player2.name+ ' has lost ' + opponent.pointsAmount + ' points.');
```

So, I'd like to access the property inside `attack` function which has a value `30`. Chrome developer tools returns `opponent is not defined`. Any advices on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: replace `opponent` with `player2`

Comment: `this.name;` does absolutely nothing btw.

Comment: `pointsAmount ` would be 70, not 30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`opponent` is only defined inside of the attack method; it cannot be referenced outside of that method.  That's why this line

```
alert(player2.name+ ' has lost ' + opponent.pointsAmount + ' points.');
```

is failing.  Replace `opponent` with `player2` (there only).

On another note, there's really no reason to keep re-defining the attack method over and over and over again for each player.  You might consider defining it like this

```
Battle.prototype.attack = function(opponent) {
    opponent.pointsAmount -= 30;
    alert(this.name + " hit " + opponent.name);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables in JavaScript are just pointers to objects. In your example opponent is simply a reference to the player2 object since that is the argument you passed to the function. From outside of attack, you can simply reference the object as player2.

`alert(player2.name+ ' has lost ' + player2.pointsAmount + ' points.');`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get how many points have been lost, you have to something like..

```
var preAmount = player2.pointsAmount;
player1.attack(player2);
alert(player2.name+ ' has lost ' + (preAmount - player2.pointsAmount) + ' points.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
alert(player2.name+ ' has lost 30 points.');
```

This is fine as long as each attack costs 30 points :) . Otherwise if you want to say how many points player2 has left do:

```
alert(player2.name+ ' has ' + player2.pointsAmount + ' points left.');
```

Comment: If I replace with player2 I get the value 70. But not 30.

Comment: Because you hard-coded 30, with each attack the player will always loose 30 points :)

Comment: 30 should be a property of Battle()

Answer (score 0):

This is my variation :-) I added a new variable `pointsLostOnPrevAttack` for Battle class

```
function Battle () {
    this.name;
    this.pointsAmount = 100;
    this.pointsLostOnPrevAttack;
    this.attack = function attack (opponent) {
        opponent.pointsAmount -= 30;
        opponent.pointsLostOnPrevAttack = 30;
        alert(this.name + " hit " + opponent.name);
    };
};


player1.attack(player2);
    alert(player2.name+ ' has lost ' + player2.pointsLostOnPrevAttack + ' points and has now '+ player2.pointsAmount + " points left");
```

Now it alerts "Ipsum has lost 30 points and has 70 points left"